# How to check if a column A is linked to one or many of another column A

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table Product  that have columns as such

**Product**  (ProductName varchar(255) , component varchar(255) , Sector varchar(255)  )

| ProductName | component | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AC90120301 | AN608350000A | ZZZ |
| AC90120301 | AN609181200A | ZZZ |
| AC90120301 | AN609186600A | ZZZ |
| AC90120301 | AN609187100A | ZZZ |
| AC90120301 | AN609187500A | ZZZ |
| AC90120301 | AN609238000A | ZZZ |
| AC90112 | AN67779563 | ZZZ |

**What i want to achieve is**

How to check  If the component is linked to a single product or to products belonging to the same sectors  then the value of its sector o will be equal to that of its products.

o Ex: IF PRODUCT_1 (Sector = M1), PRODUCT_2 (Sector = M1) THEN Component (Sector = M1)

Comment: You have updated your request, but I don't understand this update. You wanted to know whether a component is linked to one product only or one sector only. You have probably seen my answer showing how to do that. Does that work for you? Or have you been mistaken in describing what you want? If so, your update doesn't clarify anything for me. So, in case you want something else, then edit your request again and show the result table you are after. And you should alter your description then, too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by component and count:

```
select
  component,
  count(distinct productname) as number_of_products,
  count(distinct sector) as number_of_sectors
from product
group by component;
```